# How to add Synology NFS share to ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esxi, nfs, network-attached-storage, synology

I have created an nfs share on a synology NAS. I want to add the share to an ESXi host, but without success.

Configuration of the nfs share:

I inserted the IP of the ESXi host, allowed read/write and tried all 3 root_squash values (not assigned, guest and admin)

[image]

Adding the share to ESXi:

I inserted the IP of the NAS, the name of the nfs share (I tried both `/vms` and `vms` without slash)

[image]

This is the error message on the ESXi client:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I should insert the absolute path of the nfs folder in the second dialogue, will try and find out the path name

Comment: Have you had any success yet? I'm planning to buy a sinology box to use as a nfs share for external backups.

Comment: Hi Benedict, yes, I accepted Matt's answer, what he writes helped me, acutally it is simple if you know where. We are quite happy with Synology & VMWare. If you read the other answer (which I have written) you see how I found out the share name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as where you would find the folder path (/volume1/vms), its at the bottom of the NFS Privledges window in DSM.

Answer (score 0):

I activated ssh access on the NAS. It offers a simple busybox shell. I could see a folder "volume1" in the root folder of the filesystem and in it there was my shared directory `vms`

So I repeated to add the share to ESXi, this time I insrted /volume1/vms as Folder (second field below the IP) and it worked.

If someone can tell me how I could have found this path from the synology interface I would accept that answer.